# Laravel relationships: hasOne vs belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, activerecord, orm, eloquent, one-to-many

i have 3 tables:

```
   Schema::create('item_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsignet();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
    });

    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsignet();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('photo');
        $table->integer('item_type_id')->unsignet(); //->nullable();
        $table->integer('brand_id')->unsignet(); //->nullable();
        $table->float('price')->unsignet();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('logo');
        $table->text('description');
    });
```

need relations between them ...

so i set:

```
hasOne for item_types and brands in Item.php 

belongsToMany for Items in ItemType.php and Brand.php
```

tried alot combinations
know that's stupid, but can't do anything )

when i fill tables like this:

```
factory(App\Item::class, 5)->create()->each(function($i) {
        $i->type()->save(factory(App\ItemType::class)->make());
        $i->brand()->save(factory(App\Brand::class)->make());
}
```

getting error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'item_type_id' in 'field list'
>   (SQL: insert into `item_types` (`name`, `item_type_id`) values (et,
>   1))

if i set this in Item.php :

```
`hasOne('App\ItemType', 'id', 'item_type_id');`
```

same for brands

all the tables are filled, but item_type_id and brand_id in items table is empty

**[SOLVED]**

Answer below +

```
factory(App\Item::class, 50)->create()->each(function($i) {
    $i->ItemType()
        ->associate(factory(App\ItemType::class)
        ->create());
    $i->brand()
        ->associate(factory(App\Brand::class)
        ->create());
    $i->save();
```

Comment: Your relationships are in the wrong side. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relationships are in the wrong side. Always try to remember the dog and owner illustration:

> […] Let's say we have a Dog model and an Owner model. Immediately we can say the Owner `has_one` Dog and the Dog `belongs_to` Owner.

In your particular case your dog is the Item and their owners are ItemType and Brand:

```
# Item.php

public function itemType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ItemType');
}

public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand');
}
```

And also the other 2 classes:

```
# ItemType.php

public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
}

# Brand.php

public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: BTW, the dog and owner example isn't mine, it is from Lehman: http://inlehmansterms.net/2014/07/28/has_one-vs-belongs_to/

Comment: @hvpc I edited the title of question removing the “[SOLVED]” part, instead accept the answer if it really helped you.